# How to discover Ip Addresses where listening on port x

Tags: java, sockets, local-network, port-scanning

I would like to scan the IP range from my subnet.
I would like to save the IP addresses, which will be heard in on a specific port. I use this code:

```
        for (int host = 1; host < 255; host++) {
            String ip = networkAddress + host;

            Socket socket;
            try {
                socket = new Socket(ip, port);
                System.out.println(ip + "  +");
                serverList.add(ip);
                socket.close();
            }
            catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println(ip + "  -");
            }
        }
```

But my problem is that it takes too much time ...
Is there any faster way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use multithteading. Since most of the time is actually spent waiting for a response, you can safely create 100 (or even 200) threads, reducing the total time by two orders of magnitude. Use [`Executors`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html) class to create a thread pool and submit one task per each host.

Remember that the `serverList` collection will then have to be thread safe. Use `shutdown()` and `awaitTermination()` pair to wait for results. Alternatively use [`CompletionService`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CompletionService.html) to collect results as they arrive.

Answer (score 0):

Use `new Socket()` (no arguments) and then call `Socket.connect()` with a shortish timeout, say a few seconds.